# DOSBox says the program must be run under Win32

Tags: games, compatibility, ms-dos, dosbox

I'm trying to run a DOS game in DOSBox, but it says it must be run under Win32. The game in question was recently re-released for higher resolution and ability to run under Windows. Does it mean it's no longer compatible with DOS?

**NB** If it helps, the game is *Raptor - Call of the Shadows 2010 Edition*.

Comment: You will probably be able to run it with wine no?

Comment: @brunopereira81 Better DOS than Wine, but well, I'm downloading it as I comment anyway. Guess I'll delete the question.

Comment: so true, but depends on what you are trying to run, dos = 16bit if the application was built for 32bits that means that it would run good under windows terminal but not on dos :D

Comment: That is a great game! It was my favorite game when I was a kid, I would play it all day everyday! It was originally a DOS game but has since then been ported to Windows. To run it you need Wine. You can run the old game in DOSBox but not the 2010 Edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of EXE files for Windows is different then for DOS - Windows applications contain a small DOS stub which says "This program can not be run in DOS" and exits; Windows loader uses a different entry point.

If that message is what you see when trying to run the executable in DOSBox, then it means the executable has the new format (not surprisingly in 2010), so DOS (and DOSBox) can't load it. Try using Wine.